# ¿Como puedo hacer para que una tabla haga las funciones de eliminar y modificar? Sin tener que hacer 2 tablas independientes

Tags: php, html

Estoy apenas iniciando a utilizar PHP y el tema de formularios, por eso aun me quedan dudas de como poder utilizar las funciones.

Codigo HTML

```
    <legend>ELIMINAR</legend>
    <table class="table table-striped" summary="Tabla generica">
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Nombre</td>
            <td>Apellido</td>
            <td>Edad</td>
            <td>Eliminar</td>
        </tr>
    <?php 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `progra9a`.`princesas`;";
        $resultado= mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
            echo
             '
             <form action="../eliminar.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="princesid" value="'.$row[0].'">'.$row[0].'
                </td>

                <td><input type="text" name="princesanombre" value="'.$row[1].'"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="princesaapellido" value="'.$row[2].'"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="edad" value="'.$row[3].'"></td>



                <td><button class="eliminar" data-id="'.$row[0].'">Eliminar</button></td>
                </form>

            </tr>
            ';
        }
    ?>
</table>


    <br />
    <br />


    <legend>MODIFICAR</legend>
    <table class="table table-striped" summary="Tabla generica">
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Nombre</td>
            <td>Apellido</td>
            <td>Edad</td>
            <td>Modificar</td>
        </tr>
    <?php 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `progra9a`.`princesas`;";
        $resultado= mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
            echo
             '
             <form action="../modificar.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="princesid" value="'.$row[0].'">'.$row[0].'
                </td>

                <td><input type="text" name="princesanombre" value="'.$row[1].'"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="princesaapellido" value="'.$row[2].'"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="edad" value="'.$row[3].'"></td>



                <td><button class="modificar" data-id="'.$row[0].'">Modificar</button></td>
                </form>

            </tr>
            ';
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

Codigo PHP.
Eliminar.

Modificar

Comment: Lo que tienes que hacer es imprimir la tabla con dos botones, uno que llame a una funcion eliminar y otro a la funcion modificar. La tabla que sea modificable todo el rato, ya que no va a afectar al boton eliminar.

Comment: Una buena solución sería, como ha dicho @GDP, tener dos botones en el formulario, uno para **Eliminar** y otro para **Modificar**, cada uno con una etiqueta `id` diferente. Luego, usando Ajax, combinado con una librería como jQuery, escuchas los clicks de cada botón basándote en el `id`. jQuery determinará cuál de los dos botones fue presionado y enviará mediante Ajax una petición al servidor para ejecutar una de las dos acciones. La ventaja es que todo eso se podrá hacer sin tener que refrescar la página.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una buena solución sería, como ha dicho @GDP, tener dos botones en el formulario, uno para Eliminar y otro para Modificar, cada uno con una etiqueta `id` diferente.

Luego, usando Ajax, combinado con una librería como jQuery, escuchas los clicks de cada botón basándote en el id. jQuery determinará cuál de los dos botones fue presionado y enviará mediante Ajax una petición al servidor para ejecutar una de las dos acciones.

La ventaja es que todo eso se podrá hacer sin tener que refrescar la página.

Por ejemplo:

```js
$(function ()
{
  var btnModificar = $("#btnModificar");
  var btnEliminar = $("#btnEliminar");

  var btnClick = function(e) 
  {
    var btnPresionado = e.currentTarget.id;
    if (btnPresionado == "btnModificar") 
    {
      alert("Aquí se haría una  petición  Ajax para modificar");
    } 
    else if (btnPresionado == "btnEliminar") 
    {
      alert("Aquí se haría una  petición  Ajax para eliminar");
    } 
    else 
    {
      alert("Ninguno de los dos");
    }

    /* Se podría simplificar usando sólo esta llamada */
    /* Eliminando los tres if de más arriba */

/* 
* Comentado para evitar error en este contexto *

    if (btnPresionado)
    {
        post_data(btnPresionado);
    }
*/

  }

  btnModificar.on('click', btnClick);
  btnEliminar.on('click', btnClick);

//Ejemplo de una petición Ajax 
function post_data(accion) 
{
    /* Antes de llamar a crud.php */
    /* Agregar a data el contenido del formulario */
    /* y el contenido de accion */
 var frm=$( "#frmCrud" );

 var request = $.ajax
  ({
   url: frm.attr("action"),
   method: frm.attr('method'),
   data: data,
   dataType: "html"
  });
  
  request.done(function( msg ) 
  {
   console.log(msg);

  });
 
  request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) 
  {
   alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
  });

}


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frmCrud" action="../crud.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="princesid" value="id">
<input type="text" name="princesanombre" value="su nombre">
<input type="button" id="btnModificar" value="Modificar" />
<input type="button" id="btnEliminar" value="Eliminar" />
</form>
```

Para ver la forma de hacer peticiones al servidor mediante Ajax, puedes ver la [documentación de jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).

**Nota:**

He agregado al código una función llamada `post_data`. Para simplificar, podrías obtener el id del botón presionado, agregarlo a la variable `data`, llamar la función `post_data` y una vez dentro de ella agregar a `data` los demás elementos del formulario y hacer la llamada Ajax al servidor mediante un archivo php que yo he llamado `crud.php` (fíjate en el atributo `action` del formulario).

En el archivo `crud.php`, leyendo los datos que se han pasado podrás determinar si se ha hecho una petición de Eliminación o de Modificación y actuar en consecuencia.

`crud.php` tendría un código más o menos así:

```
if(isset($_POST["btnEliminar"]))
{
    //Código para eliminar
}


if(isset($_POST["btnModificar"]))
{
    //Código para modificar
}
```